# Is there a way to implement a TabLayout with a Viewpager, without an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tablayout

My MainActivity has a BottomNavigationView and a FragmentContainerView. The BottomNavigationView makes it possible to switch between fragments, no magic right here.

One of the fragments it navigates to, I wish to have a TabLayout with a Viewpager. Most of the tutorials work with an Activity to build the adapter etc. Is the activity really necessary or can this be done with just 2 fragments?

Comment: Please add what have you tried or piece of code from the tutorial where you are facing issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use TabLayout with a Viewpager inside a fragment. I don't know what tutorial you have been following but only change required would be when you initializing your pager adapter you need to pass `childFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager` so that your fragments state's on pager are handled properly.

EDIT: If you are passing Context to Pager Adapter then instead of `this` use `context` on Adapter initialization.

Comment: Do you have an example? Link me up :)

Comment: Hi Rafeal, please add what have you tried or piece of code from the tutorial where you are facing issue.